# How to congratulate regarding an event

Tags: collocation

I wanted to simply say congratulations to my friend for his university graduation. But I was kind of stuck for choosing the correct terms.

```
Congratulations on your graduation
```

or

```
Congratulations for your graduation
```

or what?

Answer (score 2):

You can use either "for" or "on". It's up to you that how you want to greet him. In this particular case both sentences are absolutely correct grammatically, I don't see any flaw there.

In first one :

> Congratulations for your graduation.

you are trying to greet him for the sake of whatever he has achieved, here **graduation** is the **reason** that you are greeting him. Nothing wrong in 
doing that, but context is different.

In second:

> Congratulations on your graduation

when you are using "on", it seems like you are greeting him because of "occurrence" of something, like "on Christmas". According to your intention you can use both of them.

Comment: "Congratulations for (anything)" is a very unusual phrase to use, at least in British English--don't think I've ever heard it, nor would I use it.

Comment: Yes, that is I agree, but there is nothing wrong if someone says that, is it?

Comment: I'm not a grammar expert, but I think "congratulations for" would really need to be followed by a gerund... e.g. "congratulations for graduating", "congratulations for passing your exams" etc.  But even those sound a bit strange to me.